# How do we handle timestamp formatting errors on large data imports?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

We have a large database with millions of rows of data from ship AIS pings.

We were recently formatting and importing the data from our holder, `ping_raw` relation into a `ping` relation.

During our last go at this our query was stopped: `ERROR: invalid value "2.01" for "YYYY", SQL state: 22007`. We are trying to import a `text` string (`ping_raw.datetime_pos`) into a `timestamp with timezone` field in `ping.dt_pos` using the `to_datetime()` function (in PostgreSQL 9.3).

Last thing - we searched for any values `SELECT * FROM ping_raw WHERE datetime_pos LIKE '%2.0%'`, which returned 0 rows. It seems like all the text values in `ping_raw` are formatted `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`.

Why is this error coming up? How can we successfully convert `text` value `ping_raw.datetime_pos` into a `timestamp with timezone` datatype in `ping.dt_pos`?

Comment: Please add the actual query (queries).  It's also not clear where you are trying to import from.

Answer (score 1):

We figured it out.

Some of our `timestamp` `text` data was imported in scientific notation (i.e. `2.0160924 E+13`. This threw an error, as we didn't include the `.` in the template format in the `to_datetime()` function.

Our solution was to pull the datetime from another column that contained more or less duplicate data.

Point is - the `to_datetime()` function in PostgreSQL is very particular and requires data going in to match the format you define. If you're having a similar issue run a few tests to figure out where your data isn't matching up to what the function expects.

We also saw that Postgres MAY support a conversion from scientific notation. We couldn't find anything in 9.3 that did, but it seems like it is on their list of things to implement.